# Configure ffmpeg to stream to webrtc

Tags: ffmpeg, webrtc

I'm trying to stream audio in realtime to a browser from ffmpeg. Below is my ffmpeg command and it works, except that there is a delay of 7 seconds. I play around with VLC's UDP/HTTP caching values and it still stayed at 7 seconds. With services like jitsi/google meet, it should be possible to bring this delay down to at most 1 second, if not, lower.

> ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 1M -i audio="Microphone (3- High Definition Audio Device)" -filter:a "highpass=f=380, lowpass=f=420, highpass=f=380, lowpass=f=420, volume=10" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f mp3 pipe:1 | vlc -vvv - :live-caching=300 :sout=#http{mux=mp3,dst=:8181/humming} :sout-keep

This is how the video gets loaded in HTML

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" preload="none" src="http://localhost:8181/humming" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora" autoplay="autoplay">
```

What am I missing here? Thank you.